# Recommended way to store temp files on server before commit to DB

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

NET MVC`application, in a form I have **5** file input elements and Im saving the form using`jquery ajax`.

[image]

So for a `**`**new record**`**`, the user can select a file and upload the file to the `MVC` controller but in the controller I can't save it because I dont have a primary key for the record Im going to save. So I have to store it temporarily.

> What is the best practice to do this? I was thinking on saving the `byte[]` into my `Session["appsession"]` and then when its time to submit the form in my controller I can get the `Session` and committ to server the image.

Other way maybe is on form commit to upload the files but because it's ajax that more complex to do.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using session storage.  This will cause a bloat in memory used by your application pool, or if you're using SQL Server sessions, it will slow down the application if you don't explicitly remove items from the session instance.  And when do you clean it up?  What if the same user opens the same page in the same session on two different browser windows (same browser instance)?  Session is a horribly overused choice.

You could persist to your file system, cloud storage, or a database table (as a blob).  You wouldn't believe how many applications I've had to fix where everything's dumped to session storage.  Again, avoid it.  Whatever you do, consider how you're going to do cleanup operations if the user finishes (or DOESN'T finish) the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

How about shove it here:

```
using System.IO;

string dir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
```

Then create the record, get ID, move file, delete `dir`.

Of course, now you have to worry about processing the upload and removing the file in case the first step (create-record) fails (and any misc. errors).

I'd suggest you change that workflow somehow: maybe call server to create record first, then come back to upload the file. That doesn't necessarily has to be done in 2 UI steps: wrap file-upload in FORM tag and also add a input[type=hidden], but not the rest of the input that is needed for creating that record; then onclick: AJAX to create record, which returns the ID; then set the value of the hidden field to that ID, then submit the form. Your server-side upload handler will then receive the ID and the file. Then you can update the record.

Comment: Thanks a lot your feedback was also great, actually if they allow me to check yours I will.